# Can't empty Javascript array when calling function

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, scope

I am building a simple dice game.

I have 2 arrays which represent each player and computer score.

Each time I press the "reRoll()" function, I clear all my appended divs that represent dice and I am trying to clear the array because I want the score arrays to be empty before pushing new scores for a new game.

I have a few different functions, the main one being a dice function which generates dice and generates html elements for them. I then have a wrapper function for my button, which calls dice 2 times ( I do this to roll the dice 2 times for each player. If there is a better solution than creating a wrapper function to call another function 2 times, please enlighten me ). After the wrapper is clicked, I hide the button and replace it with a new button "reRoll()", which as stated before, clears the child dice divs and allows me to play again.

The only issue I have is that each time I press "reRoll()", I the array doesn't clear and the dice score is added to the array.

I am assuming the array wont clear because it is in a local scope while the real array I am pushing to is sitting in global.

Here is the code snipet...

```js
var playerScore = [];
      var compScore = [];

      function wrapper() {
        dice();
        dice();
        document.getElementById("rollBtn").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("reRollBtn").style.visibility = "visible";
        console.log(playerScore);
        console.log(compScore);
      }

      

      function reRoll() {
        var playerScore = [];
        var compScore = [];
        console.log(playerScore);
        document.getElementById("playerRow").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("compRow").innerHTML = "";
        wrapper();
      }

      function dice() {
        let compRoll = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(7));
        var dDiceDiv = document.getElementById("compRow");
        let newDRoll = document.createElement("div");
        newDRoll.innerHTML = compRoll;
        dDiceDiv.appendChild(newDRoll);
        newDRoll.setAttribute("id", "compDice");
        compScore.push(compRoll);

        let playerRoll = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(7));
        var pDiceDiv = document.getElementById("playerRow");
        let newPRoll = document.createElement("div");
        newPRoll.innerHTML = playerRoll;
        pDiceDiv.appendChild(newPRoll);
        newPRoll.setAttribute("id", "playerDice");
        playerScore.push(playerRoll);

        var playerSum = playerScore.reduce(function (a, b) {
          return a + b;
        }, 0);

        var compSum = compScore.reduce(function (a, b) {
          return a + b;
        }, 0);

        console.log(playerSum);
        console.log(compSum);

        document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML = playerSum;
        document.getElementById("compScore").innerHTML = compSum;
      }
```

```css
#playerRow,
      #compRow {
        flex: 1;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #playerDice,
      #compDice {
        background-color: white;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding-top: 5px;
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <div
      class="container"
      style="
        width: 50%;
        background-color: lightslategray;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
      "
    >
      <h3 id="compScore"></h3>
      <div id="compRow" style="display: flex;"></div>
      <div id="playerRow" style="display: flex;"></div>
      <h3 id="playerScore"></h3>
      <button onclick="wrapper();" id="rollBtn">Roll Dice</button>
      <button onclick="reRoll();" id="reRollBtn" style="visibility: hidden;">
        Re-Roll
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Please excuse my mediocre programming ability. I am still learning javascript and would really love if someone can help solve my issue and tech me where I am going wrong. I have a feeling I could set this up so much cleaner and not run into issues like these.

PS: Please only pure JS. I am learning JS, no Jquery :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not clearing the, on top, declared arrays.
With this snippet:

```
var playerScore = [];
var compScore = [];
```

You're just declaring two new arrays, with the same name but within your scope now.
Just remove the `var` and you should be fine:

```
playerScore = [];
compScore = [];
```